# .SVG how to show (fadeIn part of image)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

In my dom i have such code:

```
<div class="icon-animated"><img src="icon_non_active.svg" id="icon_non_active"></div>
```

I have two icons (.svg):

```
icon_non_active & icon_active
```

is it possible to animate transformation from `icon_non_active` into `icon_active` and stay on active icon state (there it has one more circle)?

?

i tried this [plugin](https://github.com/alexk111/SVG-Morpheus)

but seems it's not for my case...

here are this icons:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/svg/icon_non_active.svg

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/svg/icon_active.svg

How it is possible to fadeIn this red area?

Comment: When you want to animate? onclick? on hover? ...some event with JS ?

Comment: @DaniP it doesn't matter... but in my case: after click on some dom element (not this one)

Comment: @RobertLongson maybe you can give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try overlapping each other, and since both images are the same but just a little difference you can use opacity to show the active state.

On this snippet hover the element to see it:

```css
.icon-animated {
  position:relative;
}
.icon-animated img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#icon_active {
  transition:opacity 1s linear;
  opacity:0;
}
.icon-animated:hover #icon_active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-animated">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/svg/icon_non_active.svg" id="icon_non_active">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/svg/icon_active.svg" id="icon_active">
</div>
```

Comment: yes. super-duper!
but will it work normally, for example if i set it on page scroll event?
(when visible + 100px => animate)?

also, there is almost invisible underplaying of grey part)

Comment: like this quick example https://jsfiddle.net/0k80aapf/ ?  scroll to see @brabertaser19